# Will I see the light?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, laser

There is a perfectly smooth wall. We have a slit parallel to it. Through that a laser beam passes. As the slit is parallel to wall the laser beam will hit it normally. So now if I see obliquely I shouldn't be able to view the laser dot. But that doesn't seem to be right by intuition. So will I see the dot or not and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the wall is made of a perfectly reflective material (such as a mirror) no, you won't see the dot.

However, most walls are covered with paint or made of a diffusive material : when the laser beam hits the wall, its light gets [diffused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering) in all directions. Thus you are able to see the laser spot on the wall.

To summarize : reflection depends on the smoothness of the surface, and, most importantly, on whick kind of material the surface is made of.

Comment: The reflection just depends on the smoothnes of the surface, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Think about it: you could take a granite stone and polish it almost perfectly such that its surface is just as smooth as a mirror. However, if you look at the polished stone, you wouldn't see your own reflection as well as if you would look into a mirror, wouldn't you ?

Comment: I got another doubt now... Image is the intersection of two reflected rays. And according to law of reflection angle of incidence equal to angle of reflection irrespective of the color of the reflector... So why don't we see a clear image?

Comment: Remember that what you are using (Snell-Descartes' laws) is only true in the case of a "perfect" material that does not absorb or diffuse light. Glass or liquid water follow these laws, but this is not the case for other materials such as rock, paint on a wall, wood...